# Weighted arithmetic mean with samples having zero variance

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have three samples of measures of an observable. Each sample has a different number of elements. I want to know the expected value and the variance of the observable. I assume that the probability density function of the measures follows a normal distribution.

If I only know the mean value and the variance in each sample, I believe that the expected value and the variance of the observable should be obtained using the weighted arithmetic mean. But what happens when the variance of a sample is zero (which is more possible the smaller is the sample)?

Do I need to know the values of the measures in each sample in order to calculate expected value and variance of the observable?

**Update:**

I used the inverse of the sample variance as weight. Should I follow the answer below?

[Can I get weighted sample variance from the individual variances?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545038/can-i-get-weighted-sample-variance-from-the-individual-variances?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have three samples of sizes $n_1 = 20, n_2 = 30, n_3 = 10$ and respective sample means $\bar X_1 = 35, \bar X_2 = 45, \bar X_3 = 60.$
Then the sample mean of all $n_a = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 = 20 + 30 + 10 = 60$ individuals
is

$$\bar X_a = \frac{\sum_{1=1}^{60} X_i}{n_a} = \frac{2550}{60}=\frac{n_1 \bar X_1 + n_2 \bar X_2 + n_3 \bar X_3}{n_a}
= \frac{n_1}{n_a}\bar X_1 = \frac{n_2}{n_a}\bar X_2 + \frac{n_3}{n_a}\bar X_3 =42.5.$$

In other words, you need to weight according to *sample sizes.* not inverse variances.

It is possible, but somewhat messier, to combine sample variances.
That process is based on the last member of the general formula

$$S^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2}{n-1}= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2\,\; -\; n\bar X^2}{n - 1}.$$

You would need to back-solve for the term $Q_j =\sum X_i^2$ for each sample
using its sample variance $S_j^2,$ mean $\bar X_j,$ and size $n_j,$ for $j = 1,2,3.$ Then get the combined $Q_a = \sum X_i^2 = Q_1+Q_2+Q_3$ for all three samples. Finally, along with $\bar X_a$ and $n_a,$ you could use the general formula again to get $S_a^2.$ (if you need to do this, please be careful. I recently assigned a similar problem to a class. Not liking my procedure, various
ones of them found four different, and completely wrong, formulas on the Internet.)